# Hard join query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I am migrating an old database design to a new design. The old one is a mess and very confusing ( I haven't been involved in the old design ). I've attached a picture of the relevent part of the old design below:

[image: a diagram]

The table called Item will exist in the new design as well, and it got all columns that I need in the new design as well except one and it is here my problem begin. I need the column which I named 'neededProp' to be associated( with associated I mean like a column in the new Item table in the new design) with each new migrated row from Item.

So for a particular eid in table Environment there can be *n* entries in table Item. The "corresponding" set exists in table Room. The only way to know which rows that are associated in Item and Room are with the help of the columns "itemId" and "objectId" in the respective table. So for example for a particular eid there might be 100 entries in Item and Room and their "itemId" and "objectId" can be values from 1 to 100, so that column is only unique for a particular eid ( or baseSeq which it is called in table BaseFile).

Basically you can say that the tables Environment and BaseFile reminds of each other and the tables Item and Room reminds of each other. The difference is that some tables lack some columns and other may have some extra. I have no idea why it is designed like this from the beginning.

My question is if someone can help me with creating a query so that I can be able to find out the proper "neededProp" for each row in the Item-table so I can get that data into the new design?

If I try something like below I run into problems. If I start like this and run this query

```
select * from Environment e 
  join items ei on e.eid = ei.eid
```

I get like 400000 rows which is what I want. However if I add one more line so it looks like this:

```
select * from Environment e 
  join items ei on e.eid= ei.eid
  left  join Room r on e.roomnr = r.roomobjectnr
```

I get an insane amount of rows so there must be some multiplication going on. I want to get the same amount of rows ( like 400000 in this case ) even after joining the third table. Is that possible somehow? Maybe like creating a temporary view with the first 2 rows.

I am using MSSQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from Environment e
inner join items ei on ei.eid = e.eid
left outer join
(
   select * 
   from BaseTable b
   inner join Room r on r.roomobjectnr = b.baseseq
) br on br.baseseq = e.roomnr and br.objectid = ei.itemid
```

Cheers -